# Installing PostGIS on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, amazon-rds

I am trying to follow this guide from AWS docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.PostGIS

On "Step 2: Load the PostGIS extensions", in the docs it shows `(4 rows)` but there are three rows there. Running the same commands myself up to that point, I see four rows, and the row that was missing from the docs is `tiger_data`. In Step 3, should ownership of `tiger_data` be given to rds_superuser as well?

In "Step 4: Transfer ownership of the objects to the rds_superuser role", I'm getting a syntax error from using the query provided in the docs and I don't know what to do about this:

```
postgres=> CREATE FUNCTION exec(text) returns text language plpgsql volatile AS $f$ BEGIN EXECUTE $1; RETURN $1; END; $f$;
CREATE FUNCTION
postgres=> SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser,')
postgres->   FROM (
postgres(>     SELECT nspname, relname
postgres(>     FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON (c.relnamespace = n.oid)
postgres(>     WHERE nspname in ('tiger','topology') AND
postgres(>     relkind IN ('r','S','v') ORDER BY relkind = 'S')
postgres-> s;
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE tiger.loader_variables OWNER TO rds_superuser,
                                                                  ^
QUERY:  ALTER TABLE tiger.loader_variables OWNER TO rds_superuser,
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function exec(text) line 1 at EXECUTE statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks to me like a typo in the docs - there is a `,` where there should be a `;`. The query being constructed is:

```
ALTER TABLE tiger.loader_variables OWNER TO rds_superuser,
```

But should be:

```
ALTER TABLE tiger.loader_variables OWNER TO rds_superuser;
```

So change the `SELECT` line to:

```
SELECT exec('ALTER TABLE ' || quote_ident(s.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(s.relname) || ' OWNER TO rds_superuser;')
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Is it safe to assume that the omitted `tiger_data` ownership change from Step 3 is also a mistake in the docs?